# MSB4018 The"ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I build a project in visual studio 2019 then a error came out like this:MSB4018 The"ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.Then I clean the solution and build the solution again but no result.Same error arose.Please! someone help me.

Comment: Welcome Rubel Rana! To allow people help you, I would suggest to add some more detail to your question. If you can please edit it. Eg: add some more about your development environment. Anyway, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608319/msbuild-error-msb4018-in-vs2015-the-link-task-failed-unexpectedly) could help you.

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209849/how-to-fix-this-error-on-ms-visual-studio-2019-the-resolvepackageassets-task/65514598#65514598 This is issue is happening again and again.