# How to fix this error on MS Visual Studio 2019: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. (Code: MSB4018)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm learning C# and working with VS 2019 Community (16.6.5 ver) on windows 10. Everything was OK until today. Everytime i push ctrl+F5, (i run my codes this way) VS19 show me this Error, even for Hello World! program.
I gave the Error code and description before. Here is what written under file tab in Error section:
"Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets"

Maybe this helps:
Today, for the first time i used a windows tuneup tool to do some cleanups.(360 Total Security)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, cleanup your nuget.exe packages and rebuild your project.

Comment: You can try to delete the NuGetFallbackFolder contents, which locates at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`. Then add nuget package and rebuild your solution.